# Copy image URL and paste in form on separate page

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, copy-paste

I have two pages. One is a page with a text input where you can type the url for a profile image.
There is a button next to this text are where it opens another page.

This second page you can upload images. I want to be able to click an image on this second page, have it copy the URL, close the window, and paste the URL into the input form from the first page.

Here is the code from the first page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Logo Url">Logo URL</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "{{ $affiliate->logo_url }}" name="logo_url" required>
    <button class="button" onClick="window.open('{{route('affiliate.logo')}}'); return false;">
    <span class="icon">Open</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

This successfully opens the second page.
Here I list the images uploaded with the ability to click on them.

```
foreach($imagelist as $image)
            {
                $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url('').$image['name'];
                echo '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <a href="javascript:selectImage(\''.$url.'\')" class="thumbnail">
                <img src='."$url".' class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
                </a></div><br><br>';
            }
```

Here I am able to take the url of the image and put it into the variable 'url':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectImage(imgName){
    var url = imgName;
    console.log(url);
    }
</script>
```

Console.log(url) shows that the url is coming through properly, but I have no idea how to send it back to the first page and insert it into the text input.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the popup window I simply changed the script to this:
parentform = name of form on parent window
logo_url is the name of the input in the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectImage(imgName){
    opener.document.parentform.logo_url.value=imgName;
    window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the url in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("imgName", "url");
```

and then on the other page check if it exists

```
if (localStorage.getItem("imgName")) {  
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("imgName"));
}
```

once done, remove your localStorage Item

```
localStorage.removeItem("imgName");
```

But If you are opening a pop up for image selection and your main page is still open  you can use `window.postMessage`

here is a good example from [davidwalsh website](https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage)

```
var domain = 'http://scriptandstyle.com';
var myPopup = window.open(domain + 
'/windowPostMessageListener.html','myWindow');

//periodical message sender
setInterval(function(){
    var message = 'Hello!  The time is: ' + (new Date().getTime());
    console.log('blog.local:  sending message:  ' + message);
    myPopup.postMessage(message,domain); //send the message and target URI
},6000);

//listen to holla back
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    if(event.origin !== 'http://scriptandstyle.com') return;
    console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
},false);
```

Comment: This method will detect the localStorage only item if the initial page is refreshed. Is there a way to have it automatically detect it without refreshing?

When the image select page is opened, it is opened in a new window. I would like the window to close and have the first page automatically detect the localStorage item.